# How to convert recursion to fold

Tags: scala, recursion

According to Erik Meijer, as functional programmers, we all know that instead of recursion, we should use fold. How do you convert the following to use fold? I can see one way with return, but return should also be avoided in fp. Thanks!

```
def tryOld(string: String, original: Exception, zomOldList: List[String => Double]): Double = {
  zomOldList match {
    case Nil =>
      throw original
    case head :: tail =>
      try {
        head(string)
      } catch {
        case ex: Exception =>
          tryOld(string, original, tail)
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with recursion, precisely?  Recursion is great for solving recursive problems.

Comment: Recursion works, just looking at the solution from another perspective. I replied to a post below that having function throw exception is probably a bad practice. Using fold with a Try[Double] should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution with foldLeft. It is lengthy since I first wrote a generic function which is called by tryOldString

```
  def tryOld[In, Error, Out](
    in: In,
    original: Error,
    zomOldList: List[In => Either[Error, Out]]
  ): Either[Error, Out] = {
    val seed: Either[Error, Out] = Left(original)
    zomOldList.foldLeft(seed) {
      case (prev, f) =>
        // stores first match without return
        if (seed != prev) {
          prev
        } else {
          f(in).fold(
            fa =>
              prev,
            fb =>
              Right(fb)
          )
        }
    }
  }

  def tryOutString(string: String, original: Exception, zomOldList: List[String => Double]): Double = {
    val zomFunctions: List[String => Either[Exception, Double]] = zomOldList.map {
      f =>
        s: String =>
          try {
            Right(f(s))
          } catch {
            case e: Exception =>
              Left(e)
          }
    }
    tryOld(string, original, zomFunctions).fold(
      bad => throw original,
      good => good
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can implement this with `foldRight` taking advantage of functions being values:

```
import util.control.NonFatal
def tryOld(string: String, original: Exception, zomOldList: List[String ⇒ Double]): Double = {
  val unhandled: String ⇒ Double = _ ⇒ throw original
  zomOldList.foldRight(unhandled) { (f, z) ⇒
    x ⇒ try { f(x) } catch { case NonFatal(_) ⇒ z(x) }
  }(string)
}
```

Note we use `NonFatal` here to avoid catching exceptions that we shouldn't be catching. You can write this in a more elegant way by not using exceptions directly.

Comment: This is very clever, I didn't anticipate this solution at all. It's is much cleaner than mine. However, Scala's lack of true tail-call optimization means that each call to `z` will introduce a new stack frame, potentially leading to a stack overflow. My answer suffers from the same problem.

Comment: Yeah. When I'm at work tomorrow I'll have a look at a better solution.

Comment: having function throw exception is probably a bad practice. Using fold with a Try[Double] should work.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot implement this with a fold. A fold loops over every element of a collection, whereas `tryOld` will sometimes terminate early. You could take advantage of `Stream`'s laziness and implement it in terms of `collectFirst` and `Try`:

```
import scala.util.Try

def tryOld(string: String, original: Exception, zomOldList: List[String => Double]): Double = 
  zomOldList.toStream.map(x => Try(x(string))) collectFirst {
    case Success(x) => x
  } getOrElse (throw original)
```

but your original recursive implementation is clearer and more performant.

**EDIT:**

If Scala had a `foldRight` with the same laziness properties as Haskell's `foldr`, then this could be defined in terms of `foldRight`:

```
implicit class GiveStreamAWorkingFoldRight[A](val s: Stream[A]) extends AnyVal {
  def lazyFoldRight[B](z: => B)(f: (A, () => B) => B): B =
    if (s.isEmpty) z else f(s.head, () => s.tail.lazyFoldRight(z)(f))
}

def tryOld(string: String, original: Exception, zomOldList: List[String => Double]): Double = 
  zomOldList.toStream.lazyFoldRight(throw original) { (a, b: () => Double) =>
    try {
      a(string)
    } catch {
      case ex: Exception => b()
    }
  }
```

However, Scala's lack of true tail-call optimization means that each call to `b` will introduce a new stack frame, potentially leading to a stack overflow.

Comment: If one is using Scalaz, then I believe `lazyFoldRight` already exists as `foldr` in `FoldableSyntax`.